# How To Transpose Then Split Data ( With Headers )

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been looking for a solution to my problem, I'm close but not there yet.

I'm sure the key is a clever use of **TRANSPOSE**, **QUERY**, **JOIN** and/or **SPLIT** ( I think ... ) , but I'm no Google Sheet expert so I figured I asked you for help :)

Bellow are the images to better match my scenario (string with spaces).

[image: original data - V2]

Here the result I'd like:

[image: expected result - V2]

Is there a magic formula for this?

Comment: Hmm interesting one. Not sure how I would do this in native Sheets, but should be easy enough in app script.

Comment: @New_2_Code thought so, but I seen so many codes online that were doing "kinda" the same so I thought that a Formula only method should exist .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kaam,

Here is one way...

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", QUERY(IF(A2:B<>"",A1:B1&"_"&A2:B,),,ROWS(A2:A))), " ")), "_"))
```

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: If the values have spaces, try

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", QUERY(IF(A2:B<>"",A1:B1&"_"&SUBSTITUTE(A2:B, " ", "&"),),,ROWS(A2:A))), " ")), "_"), "&"," "))
```

Comment: Thanks @JPV . It's working great! I just have a issue with my data . Actually my dataset contains values (string) with spaces in it ( in my exemple, the cell with the "A" value would have "A Z" for example ) . And that messes up with the Formula ( the A and the Z would be in different cells in the result ) . I tried to play around with the limiters being used for SPLIT and JOIN , but I can't make it work . Do you have an idea ?

Comment: @gabriel-kaam: I updated my answer. Please check out the second formula and see if that works?